# How can I prevent a user using inspect element to enable a disabled element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, security

I have a button as follows:

```
<input type="submit" class="button" value="FooBar" name="FooBar" id="FooBar" disabled="disabled">
```

I am enabling this button only when certain parameters are met. To test whether it was secure, I pressed F12 (or right click -> Inspect Element) and edited out the text *disabled="disabled"*.  Doing this overrides my code and that is scary. How can I prevent someone from changing it in this manner?

I am using php and jquery in this page and using the latter to enable or disable the button.  I have checked the jquery click function and it not only executes, but shows the button as **not** disabled. The alert below reads *Disabled: false*

```
$("#FooBar").click(function(){
    alert('Disabled: ' + $(this).is('[disabled=disabled]'));    
})
```

So how can I prevent a user from changing the button disabled state and thus overriding my logic?

Comment: you shouldn't rely on your html to handle logic, just use the disabled property to deliver the message to the user "this shall not happen" but don't do the same in your code, find a condition that you can validate to prevent the behavior fo that button.

Comment: I am doing that.  But that code results in the enabling/disabling, which can be overridden by a user, which is my problem.

Comment: You can disable F12, right click, ctrl button etc. If the information being edited so sensitive that *"it is scary"* just validate server side. They can use tools like fiddler to make Http Requests that you don't desire. Don't rely on javascript.

Comment: there is no way to prevent the user to fiddle with your code, after all is in their browser and they are free to do as they please with it. the only way to prevent any issues with users scouring your code is make your program idempotent, this way no matter what they do it wont affect it's behavior

Comment: I am evaluating server side but making changes based on user inputs.  The only other choice is load another page (from the server) for every answer from the user.

Comment: @lacripta What is idempotent and how does one do it?

Comment: it means that no matter how many times you execute an action it wont happen more than it should. by that i mean, if you have an action that creates elements no matter how many times the user clicks the button create, it will happen only once for the present data. from wikipedia "is the property of certain operations in mathematics and computer science, that can be applied multiple times without changing the result beyond the initial application."

Comment: I think I understand but that runs counter to the intent of this page, which is to present some choices to the user, look up what is possible (e.g. balance in an account), and then enable/disable choices.  Thus, the user may change her mind more than once based on the result of the look up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can disable the right-click by doing:

```
document.addEventListener('contextmenu', event => event.preventDefault());
```

but it is not recommended. Why? It achieves nothing other than the annoying user

**OR**

Alternatively, a better approach is to recheck your validations in submit action and simply returns if it fails, in this case, if user inspects and changed the state of a button, the button stays idle and will not allow to proceed

```
$("#FooBar").click(function() {
    if (!this.acceptenceCriteria()) {
        return;
    }
    alert('Disabled: ' + $(this).is('[disabled=disabled]'));    
})
```

Comment: What if user edit the `[disabled=disabled]` part too?

Comment: people can still use ctrl shift I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't stop people from using dev tools.

You can try a couple of tricks to disable right clicking (like the one below) which will stop some number of people but ultimately the solution to your problem is to use html and http properly.

```
$(document).bind("contextmenu",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Please explain "use html and http properly" in this case?