# To prevent user from enabling button using inspect element

Tags: javascript, datepicker

We are using a submit button in a timesheet which gets disabled once the month is finished. User cannot submit on next month.
**Problem** some user go to inspect element and remove disabled and submit the form.

```
<a id="submit_time_sheet_id" href="javascript:void(0);" 
  onclick="isAllDaysPunched()" class="btn btn-xs btn-primary" 
  disabled="disabled">FinalSubmit</a>
```

User removes  **disabled="disabled"** and form gets submitted.How to prevent user from modifying code

Comment: make them use a browser from the 1990's - i.e. you can't stop a user diddling in their own browser

Comment: Instead do a validation on the server side

Comment: you can't do that. but, you should make some checking in the server side.

Answer (score 1):

This will always be possible. You can't prevent anyone from using the developer tools to manipulate your form. That's why you *always have to check data sent to the server **server side***.

Answer (score 1):

“How to prevent user from modifying code?”

The answer is: you can't. How your website is opened is absolutely only decided by the respective user. Any person may download the HTML/JS/CSS source code of your website and modify it according to their needs. Or they directly invoke the form submit using tools like cURL.

The only way to prevent the submitting of data in a specified period, is to check the state – whether a user can submit data or not –on the server-side.

Comment: Code is in server side and validating by a checking the date and state also

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62148380/11406050) Answer
you can recheck your validations in the submit action.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31445762)