# How to prevent users from tampering HTML Form in the browser?

Tags: html, forms, django-forms, django-views, django-templates

I have few checkboxes in my template whos value is the id of database row. I am using AJAX to post these values back and forth.

```
{% for item in sale_order_items %}
<tr>
    <td class="text-center">
        <input type="checkbox" name="saleorderitem" value="{{item.id}}">
    </td>
</tr>
```

item.id for instance renders to 1. Now what if the user changes the value from 1 to 2 in browser using "inspect" and submits the form. what can I do at the frontend or django backend to prevent this and check if the user is submitting the same values as intended?

Comment: maybe this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46141963/how-can-i-prevent-a-user-using-inspect-element-to-enable-a-disabled-element

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, in this scenario django session variable can be used to store data between requests. When I load the form, I set the session variable to the required values, then on form submission, I check the submitted values with the values in session variable. And it works.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on many different things but to take you back to the basics: When you create a function in order to bulletproof it out of any errors you use type and value checks.

I would think the best approach to this is to add some back-end checks. The form values returned would have to adhere a set of rule such as a value threshold. If the value returned is beyond that threshold then that would mean that something has changed in the HTML.

You add a check if it fails then the back-end would return an error. In collaboration with front-end you refresh the page and return an error message. It might be really terrible UX but an average end user would never change values using their inspector.

The other alternative is to use javascript to detect any kind of HTML/DOM mutations or changes which I would advice against. Having values to be checked against specific criteria (using the back-end) is best as it foolproofs info passed on to your server against any change.